# Need to find text with RegEx and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a website to pull out some data that is stored in the body such as this:

```
<body>
    <b>INFORMATION</b>
    Hookups: None
    Group Sites: No
    Station: No

    <b>Details</b>
    Ramp: Yes
</body>
```

I would like to use BeautifulSoup4 and RegEx to pull out the values for Hookups and Group Sites and so on, but I am new to both bs4 and RegEx.  I have tried the following to get the Hookups Value:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('doc.html'))
hookups = soup.find_all(re.compile("Hookups:(.*)Group"))
```

But the search comes back empty.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

BeautifulSoup's `find_all` only works with *tags*.  You can actually use just a pure regex to get what you need assuming the HTML is this simple.  Otherwise you can use `find_all` and then get the `.text` nodes.

```
re.findall("Hookups: (.*)", open('doc.html').read())
```

You can also search by tag content with the `text` property as of BeautifulSoup 4.2

```
soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Hookups:(.*)Group"));
```

EDIT: Since BeautifulSoup 4.4, the `text` argument is named `string`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you can use `soup.find_all(text=re.compile(...))`

Comment: @sberder this answer is years old so BeautifulSoup may have updated since then, but I checked [their docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) and even with regex this *still* only applies to tags and not their contents.  I think this answer is still correct and doesn't deserve a downvote, but feel free to elaborate or you can provide another answer.

Comment: Still incorrect, you can [use regexp to match tag content](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument):

    """As with name and the keyword arguments, you can pass in a string, a regular expression, a list, a function, or the value True."""

It might have been true when you wrote your answer but is now possible.

Comment: @sberder good call; thanks for pointing that out.  I'll update the answer

Comment: @ExplosionPills it may be worth to mention that `text` argument is now called `string` (since BeautifulSoup 4.4.0). Although syntax in the above comment does still work (thanks @sberder), a more updated syntax would now be `soup.find_all(string=re.compile(...))`. The link has changed also: now it is https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument