# What's the equivalent of '*' for Beautifulsoup - find_all?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all `<tr class="**colour blue** attr1 attr2">` from a page.

The `attrs` are different each time, and some of the other sibling `<tr>s` have `colour red`, `colour pink` etc. classes.

So I'm looking for any other characters after `colour blue` in `class` to be included in the result. I've tried using `*`, but it didn't work:

```
soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'colour blue*'})
```

Thank you

Comment: so, to be clear, nothing is to occor *before* the "colour", but anything can follow "blue"? E.g., `colour bluegray maxsize tall` would match, but `altcolour bluegreen` would not?

Comment: In that case, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16421470/1085062

Comment: I tried the solutions from there, they just returned empty lists, for some reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use commonly-used [CSS Selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with beautiful soup:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
...     <tr class="colour blue attr1 attr2"></tr>
...     <tr class="colour red attr1 attr2"></tr>
...     <tr class="unwanted attr1 attr2"></tr>
...     <tr class="colour blue attr3"></tr>
...     <tr class="another attr1 attr2"></tr>
... ''')
>>> soup.select('tr.colour.blue')
[<tr class="colour blue attr1 attr2"></tr>, <tr class="colour blue attr3"></tr>]
```

`tr.colours.blue` selector will match `tr` as long as it has `colours` and `blue` class attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [regex filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

```
import re

soup.find_all('tr', class_=re.compile(r'colour blue.+'))
```

- In regex, it uses `re.search()` to find the string.
- `.` means match any character except the newline.
- `+` means match `.` more than one time.

Comment: Now you have two problems ;)