# Webscraping Python Trying to pull changing "id"

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Following is my code.

```python
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Souvenir%20P2000%20%7C%20Chainmail%20%28Factory%20New%29'
# open and read
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
#close
uClient.close()
#html parse
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
#grab all listings
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"market_listing_item_name_block"})

for container in containers:
    block_container = container.findAll("span",{"class":"market_listing_item_name"})
```

The `block_container` returns multiple results all the same, except they have in the `<span>` and
`id = "listing_#_name"` where the # is a combination of numbers that changes for each `<span>`

For example -

```
</br></div>, <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
<span class="market_listing_item_name" id="listing_2060891817875196312_name" style="color: #FFD700;">Souvenir P2000 | Chainmail (Factory New)</span>
<br/>

<span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
</div>, <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
<span class="market_listing_item_name" id="listing_2076653149485426829_name" style="color: #FFD700;">Souvenir P2000 | Chainmail (Factory New)</span>
<br/>
```

Can anyone explain how I can grab the `id` out of all the spans?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to find text with RegEx and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421038/need-to-find-text-with-regex-and-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Read the BeautifulSoup docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `id` from the `span` tags.

Try:

```python
for container in containers:
    for block_container in container.findAll("span", class_="market_listing_item_name"):
        print(block_container.attrs['id'])
```

*From Beautiful Soup Docs*

> A tag may have any number of attributes. The tag  has
>   an attribute `id` whose value is `boldest`. You can access a tag’s
>   attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary:
>
> ```
> tag['id']
> # u'boldest'
> ```
>
> You can access that dictionary directly as `.attrs`:
>
> ```
> tag.attrs
> # {u'id': 'boldest'}
> ```

Reference:

- [Beautiful Soup Docs - Attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i looked into the docs before the post really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''</br></div>, <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
<span class="market_listing_item_name" id="listing_2060891817875196312_name" style="color: #FFD700;">Souvenir P2000 | Chainmail (Factory New)</span>
<br/>

<span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
</div>, <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
<span class="market_listing_item_name" id="listing_2076653149485426829_name" style="color: #FFD700;">Souvenir P2000 | Chainmail (Factory New)</span>
<br/></div>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
containers = doc.getElements(tag='div',value='market_listing_item_name_block')
for container in containers:
  block_container = container.span 
  # or
  # block_container = container.getElement(tag='span',value='market_listing_item_name')
  # block_containers = container.getElements(tag='span',value='market_listing_item_name').contains('listing_',attr='id')
  print (block_container.id, doc.replaceReg(block_container.id,"(listing_|_name)",""))
```